# What's the Outlook default stylesheet for incoming mail?

Tags: css, email, outlook

Outlook seems to have certain CSS styles built-in for incoming mail. What are those styles? Is there a default stylesheet one can look at? If not, what's a good way to deal with that? Trial and error?

Note, that Gmail strips `<style>` tags which means that those cannot be used if Gmail must be supported.